# Scrolling to sections with offset in single page website?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make single page navigation with automatic active class on it and smooth scroll and is working fine but the problem is because of my navigation is fixed to top and thus after scrolling it covers my headings a little.

I fixed it by adding 'top - 75' to my code but after that on scrolling to a section my previous section get class active not the one who is in view.

```
var links = $('.nav').find('li');
slide = $('.slide');
button = $('.button');
mywindow = $(window);
htmlbody = $('html,body');


slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {

    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('.nav li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('.nav li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
    }

});

mywindow.scroll(function () {
    if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('.nav li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
        $('.nav li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
    }
});

function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top - 75
    }, 1000, 'swing');
}



links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);

});
```

Comment: Play with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Wqq6g/).

Comment: @mdesdev: Don't get me wrong, it's nice that you've provided the user with a Fiddle, but I'm not sure that's overly helpful in his situation. The user has working slides (like you've shown), the problem is the WAYPOINT function is firing when the bottom of the previous slide is 75px in to the view-port, hidden under the navigation bar. I don't see the point in giving him a whole new solution when he just needs a little fix.

Comment: I just think that he over complicated things, and I try to suggest him  a simpler solution ;)

Comment: the problem with your Fiddle is that if a user scroll back to 1st div after clicking on say 5th then the 5th link remains active not the 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to set an `offset` in your [Waypoint](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#docs) function, so more than 75px have to be in view before the class `.active` gets set.

```
slide.waypoint(function(event, direction) {
  // your other stuff
}, { offset: '50%' })

// only trigger when element reaches half way in the view-port
// Can set to pixels (offset: 100)
```

The problem is, I don't know if this `offset` setting only applies to the top of an element or it will work on the bottom too - haven't the time to read. Try it, if it doesn't work, you may want to have a read on other implementations of the setting, to make it work in your project. You could alternatively make your 75px navigation bar semi-transparent.